# Solution to Wave Equation via Green Function vs. Laplace/Fourier Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the inhomogeneous wave equation

$$\frac{\partial ^2\phi(x,t)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial ^2\phi(x,t)}{\partial t^2}=\delta(x)u(t)$$

on domain $-\infty < x < \infty$ and $t>0$ using two different methods. In a maths course, I learned that this equation can be solved via Greens functions

$$G(x,t,x,t')=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\delta(|x-x'|-t+t')}{|x-x'|}$$

The solution to the inhomogeneous wave equation is then given the convolution of the Greens function with the inhomogeneous term

$$\int dxdt\,G(x,t,x,t')\delta(x')u(t')=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{u(t-|x|)}{|x|}$$

However I am trying to obtain the same solution via application of Laplace and Fourier Transform. One gets then

$$-k^2\tilde{\phi}(k,s)-s^2\tilde{\phi}(k,s)=\frac{1}{s}$$

where we have initial conditions given by $\phi(x,0)=0$ and $\dot{\phi}(x,0)=0$. Rearranging yields

$$\tilde{\phi}(k,s)=-\frac{1}{s(s^2+k^2)}$$

Now taking the inverse Laplace Transform with the help of a lookup table we get

$${\hat{\phi}}(k,t)=-\frac{1-\cos(kt)}{k^2}$$

However the inverse Fourier transform of this doesn't yield the same solution as above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. After 'One gets then', you have $\phi$ as a function of $(k,s)$ and then as a function of $(k,\omega)$. Maybe a typo? 2. How did you get $1/s$ on the RHS? Taking the FT $(\hat{})$ then the LT $(\tilde{})$ yields $$\tilde{\hat{\phi}}(k,s) = \frac{\tilde{u}(s)}{s^{2}+k^{2}}$$ up to FT scaling.

Comment: @Mattos $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function, which I should have mentioned, and the $1/s$ is the Laplace transform of it.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think I found the solution. Maybe that Green functions holds only for 3+1 dimensions.

Comment: Your derivation is correct. It gives
$$\phi(x, t) =
\mathcal F^{-1} {\left[ k \mapsto -\frac {1 - \cos t k} {k^2} \right]}(x)
 \, u(t) =
-\frac 1 2 (t - |x|) \, u(t - |x|),$$
which satisfies the PDE.

Comment: @Maxim thanks, but why is the solution different from the solution obtained via the Greens function? Is my previous comment correct? Does this Green Function hold only for the case of 3 spatial dimensons?

Comment: Correct, what you wrote is Green's function for $\boldsymbol x \in \mathbb R^3$. The differential operator $L$ is translation-invariant, therefore you can find Green's function for the one-dimensional equation by applying the same method of taking integral transforms to $L G(x, t) = \delta(x) \delta(t)$:
$$G(x, t) = -\frac 1 2 u(t - |x|), \\
\phi(x, t) = \iint_{\mathbb R^2} G(x - x', t - t') \, \delta(x') u(t') \, dx' dt' =
-\frac 1 2 (t - |x|) \, u(t - |x|).$$

Comment: @Maxim Thanks. Now everything is clear to me. I did a calculation with the Laplace-Fourier-Method now with three spatial dimensions. I get a very similar result, which one would get with the Green Function method. I am not able to trace the mistake. May I send you my calculation, so you could have a look at it? It is pretty lengthy and I can't type it out here.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question about the 3D case, upload your solution somewhere and put a link to it in your question. But people are more likely to read through your solution if you type it in MathJax.